# Triangle rotation with Python

Tags: python, 3d, rotation

I have 3 points: `A, B, C`  in 3D space. AC = BC in length. They represent a triangle object called `T`. Each point is a tuple of floats representing it's coordinates.
`T` is placed such as median point from `A` and `B` is in axes origin already.

In my API, I can rotate `T` globally, that is with respect to any one global axis at a time, for rotation.
Pseudocode for this API is like:

`T.rotate('x', angle)` for rotating `T` around global `x` axis of angle value, with right hand rule.

My question is for the code to rotate `T` such as:

- `A` and `B` are on `x` axis
- `C` is on `y` axis

I suppose I will need 3 calls in succession, for rotating around each of the axes. But I have troubles figuring the angles by initial points coordinates.

Comment: Please give more details, such as example inputs and desired outputs. Also, what do "median point from A and B" and "in axes origin" mean? (A median is not a point: do you mean midpoint? And is that midpoint guaranteed to be at the origin?) How do you know it is possible to do what you want? (It does not look possible in general to me without more operations or limitations on T. For the latter, the origin must be the foot of the altitude from point C to side AB.) Finally, what work have you done on this so far and what code have you tried?

Comment: sorry, i really meant midpoint.
And with axes origin I mean the center of axes, (0,0,0)
AB midpoint is certainly in (0,0,0)

Comment: If you meant midpoint then what you ask is possible only if side length AC equals side length BC--i.e. AB is the base of an isosceles triangle. It can work with rotations around the main axes only if the origin is the foot of the altitude from C to AB--i.e. only if the vector from A to B is perpendicular to the vector from the origin to C. This is true because all of your rotations leave the origin in place, and at the desired end the situation I state will be true. If you change the condition I can give you an answer, but no answer is possible now.

Comment: yes, AC = BC in length.

Comment: Wow, that is a critical piece of information that should be in your question--please edit your question and add it. Also, what direction is the rotation in your API. Does it follow the right-hand rule? (I.e. if your right thumb points in the positive axis direction and you curl your fingers, your fingers are pointing in the direction of the rotation.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED to include angle calculations.**

Since you do not provide any real code in your question, I'll just provide an algorithm and angles. If you improve your question with code I can add some code of my own.

To clarify, we must have length `AC` equal to length `BC`, and the midpoint of side `AB` must be the origin. That latter means that the coordinates of points `A` and `B` are negatives of each other. (Actually, the real requirements are that the vector `OC` where `O` is the origin is perpendicular to the vector `AB` and that origin is in line `AB`. Your conditions are more strict than this.)

Let's say that at any point the coordinates of `A` are `(Ax, Ay, Az)` and similarly for `B` and `C`.

First, move point `A` to the xy plane. Do this with a rotation of all three points around the x-axis. Due to the conditions, point `B` will also be in the xy plane. One possible angle of the rotation is `-atan2(Az, Ay)` though others are also possible. Check that the resulting values of `Az` and `Bz` are zero or close to it in floating-point precision.

Second, do a rotation around the z-axis to move point `A` to the x-axis (and the other points appropriately). Point `B` will now also be on the x-axis. One angle of rotation for this is `-atan2(Ay, Ax)`. Check the resulting `Ay` and `By`.

Third and last, do a rotation around the x-axis to move point C to the y-axis. Points `A` and `B` will not be affected by this last rotation. One angle of rotation for this is `-atan2(Cz, Cy)`. Check the resulting `Cx` (which should have been zero before this last rotation) and `Cz`.

Your triangle is now in the desired position, provided your original triangle actually met the conditions. Note that this algorithm did not use any rotation around the y-axis: it was not needed, though you could replace my initial rotation around x with one around y if you want.

Comment: I had elaborated a solution like this. I see that you use 3 rotations, with alpha, beta,gamma angles respectively. Considering that we might use standard math functions, like cos,sin,tan,acos,asin,atan, plus distance functions between points etc, I wonder how to work out alpha, beta and gamma from A,B,C coordinates and then apply them.

Comment: @user1941583: I have included the angles. Only `atan2` or `atan` and the coordinates are needed. I prefer `atan2` since that avoids possible exceptions.

Comment: Your solution is elegant and straightforward. Unfortunately it is incremental. That is, as far as I understand, at each step I must rediscover the new coordinates.

Comment: @user1941583: Yes. That seemed to be implied by your " I will need 3 calls *in succession*". It would be possible to work only from the original coordinates but that would repeat much of the rotation code, violating [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Is there a problem with "incremental"?

Comment: Not a philosofical problem. I'm deriving this formulae for manipulating a mesh of points. exact coordinates are just centroids of subparcels of the mesh, extracted from the whole under certain filters. So I try to minimize recalculating things